# sequence that satisfies the equation : $x_{n}^{n}+x_{n}^{2}+2x_{n}-1=0 $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $x_n$ be a sequence that satisfies the equation  : 
$$x_{n}^{n}+x_{n}^{2}+2x_{n}-1=0 $$ and converge to some $l\in [0,1] $

$$\forall n\geq 3,\quad x_{n}\in[0;1] $$

What is its limit ?

$$\begin{cases}
x_n^{n}\to ? & \\
x_{n}^{2} \to l^2& \\
2x_{n}\to 2l 
\end{cases}$$ then 
$$?+l^2+2l-1=0 $$

- In case of $l=1$

I'm stuck here

Comment: Well, show that $l = 1$ is impossible. Look at $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} (x_n^n + x_n^2 + 2x_n) \geqslant \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} (x_n^2 + 2x_n)$.

Comment: That's not a sequence - it's  an equation.

Comment: I suppose $x_n$ is a sequence that satisfies the equation and converges to some $l \in [0,1]$ (rather than being defined by the equation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$l$ may not be $0$, for otherwise taking the limit in the equation that defines it would yield $-1=0$.

$l$ may not be $1$, for ${x_n}^2+2x_n-1\to2$ as $n\to\infty$ and hence the equation that defines it would not be fulfilled as $n\to\infty$.

If $l\in(0,1)$, then ${x_n}^n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence, the limit must satify $l^2+2l-1=0$, or $(l+1)^2=2$. It follows that $l+1=\pm\sqrt{2}$, and since $l\in(0,1)$ it must be $l=\sqrt{2}-1$.